# Getting value of checkbox using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a problem with getting values of `checkbox` in angular. Here is the snippet:

```
<div class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
   <input
      type="checkbox"
      [name]="ticket.id"
      [id]="ticket.id"
      [value]="ticket.id"
      formControlName="ticketTypes"
   />
   <label for="{{ ticket.id }}">{{ ticket.name }}</label>
</div>
```

I am getting above checkbox's value as `true`. How to get checkbox value correctly ?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyfxea)

Comment: Are you using ngForm or Reactive Forms?

Comment: @GangadharGandi i am using reactive form.

Comment: Please paste the code of component.ts as well

Comment: Hey you can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-checkbox or https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(change)` which fires every time when change detects on the input element and then write a custom logic to get the checked items from list, for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
    <input type="checkbox" [name]="ticket.id" [id]="ticket.id" [value]="ticket.id" (change)="onCheck(ticket.id)"/>
    <label for="{{ ticket.id }}">{{ ticket.name }}</label>
</div>

<pre>{{tickets | json}}</pre>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  tickets = [{ id: 1, name: "Test1" }, { id: 2, name: "Test2" }];

  checkedTickets = [];

  onCheck(evt) {
    if (!this.checkedTickets.includes(evt)) {
      this.checkedTickets.push(evt);
    } else {
      var index = this.checkedTickets.indexOf(evt);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.checkedTickets.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.checkedTickets);
  }
}
```

**[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqktun)**

Comment: But I don't think this will solve the OP's problem though, IMO you cannot just use formControl like this in checkbox, can you provide working demo for the same

Comment: Without the formcontrolname,just using `(change)="onCheck(ticket.id)"` by keeping the checked items in an array works for me

Comment: and what if flow goes like `check` -> `uncheck` -> `check` this will add duplicate entries in array, you need a custom logic to handle this again. So Overall I don't recommend using this scenario.

Comment: At the end this solution is fine if user don't want to add extra property in the existing object but if the `[(ngModel)]` works fine then its better one

Comment: @PrashantPimpale but while you deal with such a long form you generally avoid using `ngModel` an extra variable for the same, so in those cases `formArray` would be beneficial. your thougts?

Comment: Looking forward to the better way to do this :) I always write custom logic as I added in the demo to handle cases like this

Comment: @AdritaSharma Test: `Click Test1 then Test2 then uncheck Test1 it shows empty array` but expected `Test2`

Comment: True @PrashantPimpale this is one among many example for custom logic, I always avoid this :|

Comment: @AdritaSharma Your solution *is not wrong* nither *bad one* but sometimes we need to handle multiple use cases to get it done properly!

Comment: Ya.. but ofcourse it is simple if this can be done without any custom logic. btw fixed the issue

Comment: Please check stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

In such scenarios better/recommended to use `formArray` if you are dealing with the form or you can use simply `ngModel` two way data binding of Angular.

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit(form.value)">
  <div *ngFor="let s of addOns.controls; let j=index">
   <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="s"/> {{user1.addOns[j].name}}
  </div>
 </form>
```

Also simply `formControlName` i.e single control is generally used while dealing with `Radio Buttons` because in that case user can select always single value but here in case of `checkboxes` you can select multiple entries as well, which is designed like this, So you might use `array` in that case like above in my example.

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-checkbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Or in case you want to use `ngModel` you can use it like this -

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checked">{{item.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I would go with `[(ngModel)]="item.checked"` which is clean and easy!

Comment: Cool, always your choice :) @PrashantPimpale but while you deal with such a long form you generally avoid using ngModel an extra variable for the same, so in those cases formArray would be beneficial. your thougts?

Comment: Yes, even No need to add extra feild to maintain the state `(Checked/Unchecked)`

Comment: yeah @PrashantPimpale :) hit thumbs Up if you like the way I handle this :P

Comment: please check stackblitz